# Question about the period of specific Hamiltonian flows

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, hamilton-equations

Consider the Hamiltonian of the form $H(q,p)=p^2/2 + |q|^{\beta}/\beta$ for $\beta\in (1,2)$.

In the case of $\beta=2$, this is simply the harmonic system and we know that all contours, i.e. those of the form $\{(q,p):H(q,p)=E\}$ for fixed $E>0$ are circles and has a circumference of radius $\sqrt{q^2+p^2}=\sqrt{2H(q,p)}$ and the speed of the Hamiltonian flow is $\sqrt{J\nabla H(q,p)}=\sqrt{q^2+p^2}$ for $J=\begin{pmatrix}0 && 1 \\ -1 && 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

So the relation time=distance/speed tells us that the period length is $2\pi$ independent of the starting position.

My question is what happens to the period length of the contours as $|q|$ gets large, or the energy level increases? The speed will be $\sqrt{p^2 + |q|^{2\beta - 2}}$ where $2\beta-2 \in (0,2)$.

So the distance between $q$ for each level contour will increase as $|q|$ increases. I think the period length increases as a result of this but I am not sure about this. I would greatly appreciate any insight into this.

Comment: This question seems (at least partially) ill-defined. You claim you want the period length as $q$ gets large but this does not make sense since the period length depends on the whole contour line (in fact, the period length could be written as an integral over the contour line). It's pretty much like saying you want to calculate the length of the curve $(x,y(x))$ as $x$ gets large; it simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does make sense to ask it for the case when $E$ gets large. I set up the integral but it's too hard to do explicitly. Did you find this problem in a textbook or did you come up with the question on your own, btw?

Comment: Looks like the restoring force will be greater than the harmonic oscillator’s for small $q$, and less than the HO’s for large $q$.  So one would expect the period to go from less than $2\pi$ to greater than $2\pi$ as the energy / maximum displacement increases.  Also I suspect that $\beta=1$ admits an exact solution?

Comment: Right, so for $\beta=1$ you just have $\dot{p}=\pm 1$, and so the period is twice the maximum value of $|p|$, or $2\sqrt{2H}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice problem. Being in two dimensions, you may use action-angle variables to calculate the period of the motion as a function of energy using a simple area formula (see e.g. V.I.Arnold, Math methods of classical mechanics, either chap 50 or the Problem on page 20, albeit without any solution given).

More precisely, given $E=H_\beta(p,q)>0$ and $|p|\leq \sqrt{2E}$ we have in the present case that $q=\pm f_\beta(p,E)$ with
$$ f_\beta(p,E) = (\beta (E-p^2/2))^{1/\beta} .$$

The area of the set  $\{(p,q): H_\beta(p,q)\leq E\}$ is then given by:
$$ A_\beta(E) =\int_{H_\beta\leq E} dq\wedge dp = \oint_{H_\beta=E} q \; dp = 4\int_0^{\sqrt{2E}} f_\beta(p,E)dp$$
where I used Green's formula and
in the last formula the symmetry of the orbit. Making the substitution $p=\sqrt{2E} \; u$ we obtain:
$$A_\beta(E) = E^{1/2+1/\beta} C_\beta.$$
Here $C_\beta= 4\sqrt{2} \beta^{1/\beta} \int_0^1 \left(1-u^2\right)^{1/\beta}$ only depends upon $\beta$.
The formula given in Arnold's book now states that
the period of the orbit is simply given by the derivative of this area with respect to energy, i.e.:
$$ T_\beta(E) = \frac{\partial A_\beta}{\partial E} =
  E^{1/\beta-1/2} \left( \frac12 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)
 4\sqrt{2} \beta^{1/\beta} \int_0^1 \left(1-u^2\right)^{1/\beta}.$$
Even if we don't know the explicit value of proportionality,  we may still deduce the behavior of the period when changing the energy.
We see  that $T_2(E)$ is independent of $E$ (as we knew). For $\beta>2$, $T_\beta$ is decreasing with $E$ while for $0<\beta<2$, $T_\beta$ is increasing with $E$. In some cases we may calculate an explicit formulae (possibly needing interpretation as the dynamical system is not regular for some of the $\beta$-values):
$$ T_{1/2}(E) = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2E}^3, \ \ \ T_1(E) = 4 \sqrt{2E}, \ \ \ T_2(E)=2\pi, \ \ \ T_\infty(E)= \frac{4}{\sqrt{2E}}.$$

I believe this should answer your question.